# One session should complete a php function before other session enter into function, how?

Tags: php, function, locking

Suppose that I have a function in php like:

```
function post_data()
{

   // Do the job
}
```

Now I want this function to complete for the current visitor first before other visitors enter the function. Other visitors should pass this function and do the remaining script jobs. I searched for this problem too much but could not find a proper answer. What I found is that to use flock() php function. I tried flock() and it worked best for me but I want an independent solution to this.

So how can this function be locked for one visitor before other enter the function without using flock()?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to lock an entire function in a situation like this; you are basically *serializing* your site's data processing. You really need to narrow it down as close as you can to only what code needs synchronization.

And where ever you end up having to `lock`, you are best not trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I am trying to write my cron function so if 2 or more visitors come at same time they will read all the cron stored values at the same time and will run that function. Thats why I want it to finish for first visitor and the function should not run until next schedule cron time.

Comment: @Kashif Javed - I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are doing; What does the function you have quoted above actually do, precisely? How long does it take? What do you expect to happen if another visitor comes along while the first one is still in that function? Does this function run on all requests to the site, or only a certain subset of times, or only for certain users, or only when someone visits a certain page?

Comment: The function runs for all visitors. The function above is nothing that is just I supposed that if I have a function like that and only one visitor should complete at a time. Other visitors should return while one is doing the job. The function can be used for any purpose. It should not be matter how long it takes or what it have to do.

Comment: It very much *does* matter how long it runs or what it does, without knowing how you want to make it non-concurrent. More later..